# TitleBox .seq2 animation files

Tags: codec, animation

I am using TitleBox for dynamic graphic animations.
There are several was to play an animation in this tool, but the "safest" seems to be the internal "animation file" object, which comes with a tools to create an "image sequence file" from a list of pictures ( .png / .tga  ). Such sequences files, once generated, have a .seq2 extension.

My question is: does anyone know about this format ? Is there a cli tool with which I could create a batch which would generate the .seq2 files?